# L^2 function also bounded almost everywhere?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $B$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose we have $f\in L^2(B;\mathbb{R})$ such that $$||f||^2=\int\limits_B(f(x))^2dx < \infty.$$
How can I show that $f$ is pointwise bounded almost everywhere, i.e. there exists $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\leq f(x)\leq b$ for almost all $x\in B$?

Comment: Why do you think this is true? It would mean that $L^{\infty}(B,\mathbb{R})$ coincides with $L^2(B,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I mean if it is not bounded almost everywhere, then the integral surely wouldn't be finite?

Comment: Investigate $B=[0,1]$ and the functions of the form $x^p$ for $p < -1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't show that in general.

**Example.** Denote by $\lambda$ the standard Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $B=\bigsqcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$, where $\lambda(B_n)=1/n^{2}$ (note that $\lambda(B)$ is finite, so one can find a bounded measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with these properties). Now take function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{1/3}\mathbf{1}_{B_n}(x)$ (here $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ is the characteristic function of a set $A$). It is clear that $f$ is measurable and
$$
\|f\|^2=\int_{B}|f(x)|^2dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot n^{2/3}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-4/3}<+\infty.
$$
However, there is no $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for almost all $x\in B$ (this inequality doesn't hold on $B_n$ where $n>M^3$).